# Different UI script to execute depending on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my UI's split up in 2 javascript files. If the URL is of certain patter lets say /test1 then I want script1 to execute or in other words, I want script1 to be added as `<include>` so the UI renders according to script1 else I want script2 to be added for /test2.

There is no button that triggers these URLs. Its when the page loads -detect URL and load script accordingly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*you can dynamically insert javascript file.*

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function loadJS(file) {
        // DOM: Create the script element
        var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
        // set the type attribute
        jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
        // make the script element load file
        jsElm.src = file;
        // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
        document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
    }
    if(type === "test1")
        loadJS('file1.js')
    else
        loadJS('file2.js'); 
</script>
```

Comment: Its not on button click, its when the page loads

Comment: call the function on the page load, according to your condition.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url=location.href//get the page url
    var scriptUrl
    if(url.indexOf('something')>0){//check for specific string in url
    scriptUrl='/script1.js'
    }
    else{
    scriptUrl='/script2.js'
    }

    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );//create script element
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = scriptUrl;
    $("head").append( script );//append newly created script element to head

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query String** Examples:

- ?page=**test1**
- ?page=**test2**

Following code will check the value of **page** and then load the appropriate Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var page = $.getUrlVar("page");

  var scriptToRun = null;

  switch (page) {

    case "test1":

      scriptToRun = "script1.js";

      break;

    case "test2":

      scriptToRun = "script2.js";

      break;

  }

  // Create Script Tag

  var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.type = 'text/javascript';

  script.src = scriptToRun;

  $("head").append(script);

});
```

Be sure to **add** the following **Extension** before your **$(document).ready** code:

```
$.extend({

  getUrlVars: function(){

    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {

      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];

    }

    return vars;

  },

  getUrlVar: function(name){

    return $.getUrlVars()[name];

  }

});
```

(This jQuery Extension is not my Code).